# nvidia on ubuntu 10.10: switching dvi socket

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-10.10, xorg.conf

i have ubuntu 10.10 x86_64 with nvidia 9800 gt and nvidia driver version 270.41.06

my video card has two DVI sockets, but i only use single monitor configuration. Now, i think the main DVI socket might be busted, so i want to try to enable the other as the main one, however, i don't know how to achieve that. I tried just plugging the monitor in that socket but it won't just auto-detect (it would have been way too easy to just work)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you were almost there.

1. Shutdown
2. Switch video connections to the one you want
3. Boot up

Your machine should auto detect what port to use on boot. It's possible you may need to reconfigure X too. If that ends up being the case, I'd suggest you move your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file (so you still have it, but so a new config must be generated).